# Страница авторизации для вк

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Возможно ли как-то изменить дизайн/оформление Layout'а авторизации вконтакте.
Дело в том что, вк предоставляет свой Activity и Layout для авторизации, хотелось бы как-то его изменить внешний вид. Для наглядности прикреплю скрин данного Layout'а.

---

Или стоит в этом случае стоит отказаться от использования SDK и перейти на API?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить дизайн/оформление Layout'а авторизации вконтакте не получится и через API тоже, если использовать OAuth2.

Можете посмотреть [VK notifer на java](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144813/)

Comment: Интересно тогда, как реализованы приложения KateMobile или официальное приложение для вк, там ведь свои формы для авторизации

Comment: @Heaven Вы не правы, как раз недавно я устанавливал защиту от входа на страницу с помощью кода в телефоне, и там была стандартная форма авторизации. Можете попробовать сами прикрепить(или открепить и заново прикрепить) чтобы убедиться в этом.

Comment: @Heaven Вы смотрели как в статье реализовано, вот примерно так и делают если надо свой layout. А вообще лучше не изменять, т.к. стандартное пользователю ближе, не будет думать что вы пароль стырите.